# Conectar 3 tablas en uno solo y obtener datos

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de conectar 3 tablas en uno solo para obtener una información de un jugador en especifico, lo que sucede es que al querer obtener los datos de la tabla **match** este no me devuelve nada, no me arroja ningun logs o algo que me diga el porque no me devuelve los datos que estoy pidiendo

```
$query2 = $db->query('
    SELECT users_stats.*, `match`.id, `match`.pug_hash, `match`.pug_map, 
        `match`.pug_twin, `match`.pug_score_ct, `match`.pug_score_tt, 
        `match`.pug_rwin, `match`.pug_date, `match`.pug_server 
    FROM users_stats 
    LEFT JOIN users_match ON users_match.user_steamid = users_stats.user_steamid 
    LEFT JOIN `match` ON `match`.id = users_match.id '.$ext_query.' 
    ORDER BY `match`.id DESC LIMIT 0,5
') or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));
```

En esta consulta tomo como base la tabla **users_stats**, la cual quiero que se enlace con la tabla **users_match** por medio de la columna **user_steamid** y luego de ese enlace, enlazar la tabla **users_match** a la tabla match por medio del **pug_hash** o **id**

la variable **$ext_query** es la que me obtiene la id del jugador la cual le quiero sacar información de otras tablas la cual están ya en el codigo.

Si necesitan que tenga que aportar otra cosa para dar una mejor aportación no duden en comentar para yo poder subir todo lo necesario o lo que se necesita para ayudarme a corregir mi problema.

adjunto capture de las 3 tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

**Consideraciónes con el uso de LEFT JOIN**

Muy distinto a como sucede con INNER JOIN en LEFT JOIN es importante el
orden de las tablas a consultar por ende obtendras resultados distintos
dependiendo desde donde se hace el LEFT JOIN.

La Norma es comenzar desde la tabla en la que se desea que se muestren
los registros al final, en el caso tuyo si la tabla que te importa es
match entonces esa debería ser la primera tabla y desde ahí hacer los
LEFT JOIN's

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay un detalle que también veo en tu tabla match y es que para hacer el LEFT JOIN usas la clave primaria de dicha tabla, no veo una FK, pero como no conocemos la estructura total de tus tablas no podríamos concluir algo.

Según lo que lo que creo tu código debería quedar así:

```sql
SELECT
    match.*,
    users_stats.*
FROM
    match
LEFT JOIN users_match ON
    ...
LEFT JOIN `users_stats` ON
    ...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, hice la corrección al código
$query2 = $db->query(' SELECT match.*, users_stats.* FROM match LEFT JOIN users_match ON users_match.user_steamid = users_stats.user_steamid LEFT JOIN users_stats ON match.id = users_match.id '.$ext_query.' ORDER BY match.id DESC LIMIT 0,5 ') or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));

Comment: pero me salta el error 
Error en la consulta: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '*, users_stats.* FROM match LEFT JOIN users_match ON users_match.user_steamid...' at line 1

Comment: ``LEFT JOIN users_stats ON match.id = users_match.id '.$ext_query.' `` , no puedes usar un campo el cual no esta en en la tabla a la cual estas haciendo el LEFT JOIN, debería ser ``LEFT JOIN users_stats ON match.id = users_stats.id '.$ext_query.'`` , si es que existe ese campo en tu tabla.

Comment: me sigue dando el mismo error y no entiendo
Error en la consulta: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '*, users_stats.* FROM match LEFT JOIN users_match ON users_match.user_steamid...' at line 1

realice una consulta casi igual a esa y me funciono perfectamente claro en la otra no llamo a la tabla match pero en la base de datos tengo las 3 tablas y las 3 tablas tienen sus columnas y asi tal cual como las llamo aqui estan nombradas en la base de datos

Answer (score 0):

```php
$query2 = $db->query('
    SELECT users_stats.*, `match`.id, `match`.pug_hash, `match`.pug_map, 
        `match`.pug_twin, `match`.pug_score_ct, `match`.pug_score_tt, 
        `match`.pug_rwin, `match`.pug_date, `match`.pug_server 
    FROM users_match 
    LEFT JOIN users_stats  ON users_match.user_steamid = users_stats.user_steamid 
    LEFT JOIN `match` ON `match`.id = users_match.id '.$ext_query.' 
    ORDER BY `match`.id DESC LIMIT 0,5
') or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));
```

De esta manera mostrará los registros que se encuentren en `users_match`, aunque no tengan registros en las otras dos tablas.

Comment: Las 3 tablas si tienen registro, me salta el siguiente problema 
Error en la consulta: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'match ON match.id = users_match.id where users_stats.user_steamid='STEAM_0:0...' at line 1

Comment: REVISA QUE LOS CAMPOS CON LOS QUE ESTAS UNIENDO LAS TABLAS SEAN DEL MISMO TIPO DE DATO, O QUE LA TABLA SI SE LLAME MATCH

Comment: Si, el nombre de la tabla es correcta lo que no entiendo es a que te refieres a que sean del mismo tipo de dato.